# Long loading query

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

i have a query that loads ~1600 lines. 
I use in HeidiSQL to run querys (but they are coming from php/mysqli app). 
On my test base it takes ~12 seconds to load and on client ~40 seconds (In php id doesnt even compleate).

My question is is my query bad? What coul be otimized?

P.S. I will not post creat querys for tables now as they have lot of columns. Also i did not know if i should leve all paramaeters in select so i did not removed them.

```
SELECT l.id AS lid, l.doc AS receive_doc, l.thisTransport AS receive_transport, l.productNr AS receive_productNr, 
l.activityDate AS receive_date, h.ladingNr AS receive_ladingNr, l.place_count AS receive_place_count,
h.cargo_status AS receive_cargo_status, h.client AS client, e.id AS eid, e.doc AS doc, e.deliverydate AS deliveryDate, 
e.activitydate AS activityDate, e.assistant_amount AS assistant_amount, e.amount AS amount, e.productnr AS productNr, 
e.productumo AS productUmo, e.status AS status, e.orgline, ni.name1, ni.name2, h.agreements AS agreements, nc.Name,
a.uom AS uom, au.uom AS auuom ,

(select z.status       from ledger_entry as z where (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.doc=l.doc ORDER BY z.id DESC LIMIT 1) as istatus,
(select z.place_count  from ledger_entry as z where (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.doc=l.doc ORDER BY z.id DESC LIMIT 1) as iplace_count,
(select z.activityDate from ledger_entry as z where (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.doc=l.doc ORDER BY z.id DESC LIMIT 1) as iactivityDate,
(select z.place_count  from ledger_entry as z where (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.doc=l.doc ORDER BY z.id DESC LIMIT 1) as iassistant_amount


FROM cargo_receive AS l 
LEFT JOIN ledger_entry AS e 
ON e.cargoline = l.id OR e.orgline = l.id 

LEFT JOIN header_receive AS h ON l.doc = h.doc 

LEFT JOIN lines_agreements AS a 
ON h.agreements = a.contractnr 
AND e.productnr = a.item 
AND e.resource = a.service

LEFT JOIN uom AS au 
ON e.productnr = au.productnr 
AND au.status = 1 
AND au.convert_from = 1    

LEFT JOIN customers AS nc
ON h.client=nc.Code    

LEFT JOIN items AS ni
ON l.productNr=ni.code    


WHERE h.client='1234567' AND h.agreements='AG000001'

GROUP BY l.id
ORDER BY l.activityDate ASC, l.doc
```

**EDIT:**

**cargo_receive:**

```
CREATE TABLE `cargo_receive` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `doc` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `productNr` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `place_count` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `activityDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `thisTransport` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `orgLine` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `status` (`status`),
    INDEX `doc` (`doc`),
    INDEX `productNr` (`productNr`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**ledger_entry:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ledger_entry` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `doc` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cargoLine` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deliveryDate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `activityDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `productNr` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `productUmo` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,    
    `amount` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `assistant_amount` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `orgLine` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `resource` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT '',
    `place_count` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `doc` (`doc`),
    INDEX `productNr` (`productNr`),
    INDEX `cargoLine` (`cargoLine`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**header_receive:**

```
CREATE TABLE `header_receive` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `doc` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ladingNr` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `agreements` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `client` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cargo_status` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `doc` (`doc`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**lines_agreements:**

```
CREATE TABLE `lines_agreements` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `contractNr` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `service` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',    
    `item` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `uom` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `contractNr` (`contractNr`),
    INDEX `item` (`item`),
    INDEX `service` (`service`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

**uom:**

```
CREATE TABLE `uom` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `productNr` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `uom` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `convert_from` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `productNr` (`productNr`),
    INDEX `status` (`status`),
    INDEX `convert_from` (`convert_from`),
    INDEX `uom` (`uom`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

**customers:**

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
    `Code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `InsertDateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `recordId` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`Code`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**items:**

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `code` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,

    `name1` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `name2` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

EDIT:
I found out that these queries is guilty. If i remove them it woks fast (1 sec).

```
(select z.status       from ledger_entry as z where (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.doc=l.doc ORDER BY z.id DESC LIMIT 1) as istatus,
(select z.place_count  from ledger_entry as z where (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.doc=l.doc ORDER BY z.id DESC LIMIT 1) as iplace_count,
(select z.activityDate from ledger_entry as z where (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.doc=l.doc ORDER BY z.id DESC LIMIT 1) as iactivityDate,
(select z.place_count  from ledger_entry as z where (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.doc=l.doc ORDER BY z.id DESC LIMIT 1) as iassistant_amount
```

If i turn them into left joins its still same slow query:

```
z.status as istatus,
z.place_count as iplace_count,
z.activityDate as iactivityDate

LEFT JOIN item_ledger_entry AS z
ON (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id) AND e.docNr=l.docNr
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`OR` is a performance killer.  It usually ends up doing a full table scan.  For example:

```
        SELECT  z.place_count
            from  ledger_entry as z
            where  (z.orgLine=l.id
                OR  z.cargoLine=l.id
                   )
              AND  e.doc=l.doc
            ORDER BY  z.id DESC
            LIMIT  1
```

will scan all of `ledger_entry`, checking the two columns of each row for that id.  Can you restructure things so that there is not 2 columns to look in?

And what is `AND  e.doc=l.doc` doing here?  It seems out of place.

It seems to be a "groupwise-max" problem, plus some extra baggage.  See the tag I added.

This idea, on the other hand, may be the start of a better idea:

```
LEFT JOIN item_ledger_entry AS z
       ON (z.orgLine=l.id OR z.cargoLine=l.id)
      AND e.docNr=l.docNr
```

(Again the docNr does not belong).

```
LEFT JOIN ( ( SELECT * FROM item_ledger_entry WHERE orgLine = l.id )
              UNION
            ( SELECT * FROM item_ledger_entry WHERE cargoLine = l.id ) )
```

may come closer to being efficient (and correct)

Note that the trick here is to turn `OR` into `UNION`.  Also, pick between `UNION ALL` (faster) and `UNION DISTINCT` (dedups).

Don't use `LEFT` unless you need to get nulls from a missing row in the 'right' table.  It confuses the user and/or decreases the optimization possibilities.

Add these indexes to `header_receive`:

```
INDEX(doc, client, agreements)
INDEX(client, agreements, doc)
```

Without knowing whether `LEFT` is necessary, I cannot judge which of these the Optimizer will use.  Add both.

Aren't `z` and `e` the same?  The `ON` seems to be the same (except for the spurious extra `AND`).

`lines_agreements` needs `INDEX(contractnr, item, service)` (in any order)

`JOIN` plus `GROUP BY id` implies you might have the `explode-implode` problem.  This is where the `JOIN` collect data from various tables, building a bulky table with many columns and many rows.  Then the `GROUP BY` shrinks back to what you started with.  The workaround is to *first* get `id` as expeditiously as possible.  That is, use few, if any, `JOINs` to filter down to the ids that you will ultimately need.  Put that as a "derived table" that is *then* `JOINed` to the other tables (and possibly back to the table with `id` to get more columns).  Something like:

```
SELECT lots-of-stuff
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM cargo_receive WHERE ... ) AS l1
    JOIN l2  ON l2.id = l1.id
    [LEFT] JOIN other-stuff ...
    -- no GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Thanks allot for this long answer! I have read it all and will try ASAP to test all your comments!